# d3 radar chart -- radialLine creates path but without coordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path, radar-chart

This is probably a pretty specific question:

My problem is that in d3.js i need to create a radial chart.
I created the axis and labels.
Now i want to draw the radialLine.
It creates the path objects in my HTML document,
but without any coordinates.

I think it has something to do with the way the radius/data is provided to the radialLine, but can't figure out what to change...
Hopefully someone sees my mistake.

I also created a JSfiddle:
[complete JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qgygksL/7/)

```js
//Data:
var notebookData = [{
  model: "Levecchio 620RE",
  data: [579, 8, 2.4, 256, 13.3]
}];

var categories = [
  "Price",
  "RAM",
  "CPU",
  "Storage",
  "Display"
];

var priceScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([2500,300]).range([0,100]);
var ramScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,32]).range([0,100]);
var cpuScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1.0,3.2]).range([0,100]);
var storageScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([64,2048]).range([0,100]);
var displaySizeScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([10.0,20.0]).range([0,100]);

function selectScale(category_name) {
    switch(category_name) {
        case "Price":
            return priceScale;
        case "RAM":
            return ramScale;
        case "CPU":
            return cpuScale;
        case "Storage":
            return storageScale;
        case "Display":
            return displaySizeScale;
    }
}

var scaledData = notebookData.map(function (el) {
    return el.data.map(function (el2, i) {                //el = 1 notebook
        return selectScale(categories[i])(el2);
    });
});
     
//My RadialLine
    
    //generatorfunction
    var radarLine = d3.radialLine()
      .radius(function(d) { return scaledData(d.value); })
      .angle(function(d,i) { return i*angleSlice; })
      .curve(d3.curveLinearClosed)
      ;


    //Create the wrapper 
    var radarWrapper = g.selectAll(".radarWrapper")
      .data(notebookData)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "radarWrapper")
      ;

    //Create pathlines
    radarWrapper.append("path")
      .attr("class", "radarStroke")
      .attr("d", function(d,i) { return radarLine(d); })
      .style("stroke-width", cfg.strokeWidth + "px")
      .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return cfg.color(i); })
      .style("fill", "none")
      ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your fiddle a bit to make it work:

https://jsfiddle.net/2qgygksL/75/

Basicly what i've done:

fix the color scheme

```
var colors = d3.scale.category10();
```

instead of

```
var colors = d3.scale.ordinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

added data to path

```
radarWrapper.append("path")
          .data(scaledData)
```

change radius to

```
  .radius(function(d, i) {
        return d;
  })
```

since You used something like return scaledData(d.value); where your scaledData is an array.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'm still struggling with the function(d)-stuff in d3. For now I only need to find out how to scale the radialLine a bit better -- looks too tiny :D

Comment: For 1 second I thought you were talking to yourself! Good answer, +1. @Sebastian, you don't have rep to upvote this, but you can accept the answer.